# Edit MATLAB Launcher target file

Tags: matlab

I have installed a new version of MATLAB and would like to point the existing MATLAB launcher to:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/matlab
```

What is the procedure to configure the launcher to point to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

There, you have a list of paths from where binary/scripts are read. For example, if you initially had Matlab 2015a, it might look something like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin
```

You want to change the last path to pint to the new version (this is, replace `R2015a` with `R2016b`). Save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>), exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>), and you are done.

More information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path).